# How does Customer Account Balance affects from Customer Transaction Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here I have two tables `Customer_Account` and `Cust_Transaction` with below attributes and not in much details and it is to be mentioned that relationship between tables is `Account_ID`:

```
Cust_Account(
Account_ID PK,
Account_Name,
Account_Balance)

Cust_Transaction(
Trn_ID PK,
Trn_Date,
Trn_Amount,
Trn_Type,
Account_ID FK)
```

Data in tables is below:

```
    |---------------------------------------|
    |Account_ID|Account_Name|Account_Balance|
    |---------------------------------------|
    |    0001  |    Ahmad   |      0        |
    |---------------------------------------|



    |-----------------------------------------------|
    |Trn_ID|Trn_Date |Trn_Amount|Trn_Type|Account_ID|
    |---------------------------------------------- |
    | 001  |01/01/20 |   4000   | Credit |  001     |
    |-----------------------------------------------|
```

I want a solution which whenever I entry to `Cust_Transaction` with above data it should also add the amount to his/her account in `Account_Balance` and whenever it is "Withdraw" it should minus from `Account_Balance` meanwhile when a transaction deletes, it should also minus from `Account_Balance`.
Please help me in which way should I solve it.
Thanks,

Comment: Its easier to just query the transaction table when you want the balance. Otherwise you need a trigger on the transaction table or a stored procedure to handle transactions.

Comment: Why don't the account ids match in the table tables?  (`'001'` <> `'0001'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create TRIGGER on transactions table and it perfectly will handle the balance in table:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_Cust_Transaction ON Cust_Transaction
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE CA SET Account_Balance = ISNULL(Account_Balance,0) + ISNULL(I.Trn_Amount,0) - ISNULL(D.Trn_Amount,0) 
    FROM Cust_Account CA 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Account_Id, SUM(Trn_Amount * IIF(Trn_Type = 'Credit', 1, -1)) Trn_Amount FROM INSERTED GROUP BY Account_Id) I ON CA.Account_Id = I.Account_Id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Account_Id, SUM(Trn_Amount * IIF(Trn_Type = 'Credit', 1, -1)) Trn_Amount FROM DELETED GROUP BY Account_Id) D ON CA.Account_Id = D.Account_Id
END
```

Learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql#:%7E:text=A%20trigger%20is%20a%20special,on%20a%20table%20or%20view.).

Tip: If you will never insert/update/delete with multiple records on Cust_Transaction, you can join to Inserted and Deleted tables directly and there is no need to group by data by account_id.

Comment: It just add from Cust_Transaction amount to Cust_Account Balance and if I delete a transaction it does not update the Account_Balance hence I already mention in my question that based on Cust_Transaction(Trn_Type) it should add/Minus the Account_Balance.

Comment: Actualy it does. In update line if you notice it will handle deleted record too. That's why there is left join with Deleted.

Comment: If you consider my question I already mentioned that based on transaction type which could be Credit/Withdraw, I mean if "Credit" it should add to Account_Balance and if it "Withdraw" it should deduct from Account_Balance but in this trigger it does not mentioned on it.

Comment: You absolutely right, my bad. I edit my answer. If Trn_Type is always Credit/Withdraw, so you can just check type is Credit or not. I hope there wasn't any problem this time.

Comment: By the way, if you never insert/update/delete on multiple records, you can join Inserted and Deleted tables directly and there is no need anymore to group by data by account_id.